# Getting no route found for favicon-96x96.png errors in PHP logs

Tags: html, symfony, favicon

Occasionally I see these errors in my PHP log about favicon-96x96.png not found.

It looks like this:

```
No route found for "GET /assets/favicon-96x96.png" (from "https://test-project.com")
```

My `head` element has these favicons loaded:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{ asset('favicon-16x16.png') }}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{{ asset('favicon-32x32.png') }}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{{ asset('favicon-96x96.png') }}">
```

So it should be found by any browsers without a problem.
Also I can't even reproduce this error, I only see it logged a few times a day.

Any ideas what kind of requests these could be? I don't have any controller called `assets` or any public folder named like this. Every favicon is in public folder.

If I'm not mistaken the 96x96 favicon is used by Google TV. How could I reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: Can you find the icon if you manually visit it in your browser?

Comment: Yes, but it is in public folder, not in any "assets".

Comment: Do you mean a folder called 'public'? Which directory *exactly*. And what are the braces for `{{...}}`? If they're for some framework, add the tag to your question. As it is, it's not an HTML question.

Comment: Yes, folder called "public". Braces is used by Symfony framework to get the filename.

Comment: I updated the tag. Either way, this problem still occurs even if I load the favicons without curly braces.

Comment: It doesn't matter what folder the asset is in. Can you access the url given from the browser?

Comment: No, because that URL is not existing. Thats the problem. I can't understand why these requests happen.